# How to use phantomjs in node-js environment for dynamic-page web scraping?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request, phantomjs

I am working on web scraping for few task to complete.

I have used node-js **request module** for page scraping.

It is working fine and great for cookie-session and all.

But it fails when time comes to render **Dynamic pages build with some javascript framework** like **ANGULAR** or **BACKBONE** etc.

I am trying for phantomjs to overcome this thing as i found on google that it is helpful to come over such case.

I also found one nodejs bridge for phantomjs [**phantom**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom)

With phantomjs and this bridge module i am able to achieve same thing nothing more.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var fs = require('fs');

var sitepage = null;
var phInstance = null;
phantom.create()
    .then(instance => {
        phInstance = instance;
        console.log("Instance created");
        return instance.createPage();
    })
    .then(page => {
        sitepage = page;
        console.log("createing page");
        return page.open('https://paytm.com/shop/p/carrier-estrella-plus-1-5-ton-3-star-window-ac-LARCARRIER-ESTRPLAN5550519593A34?src=grid&tracker=%7C%7C%7C%7C%2Fg%2Felectronics%2Flarge-appliances%2F1-5-ton-3-star-ac-starting-at-rs-22699%7C88040%7C1');
    })
    .then(status => {
        //console.log(status);
        console.log("getting content of page");
        return sitepage.property('content');
    })
    .then(content => {
      console.log("success");
        //console.log(content);
        fs.writeFile("ok.text", content);
        sitepage.close();
        phInstance.exit();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("errr");
        //console.log(error);
        phInstance.exit();
    });
```

Above is code which i am trying for load one of dynamic website page which is build with angular framework.

*Can anybody guide me for same or correct in above code where i am missing right things.*

Comment: I am not stuck with any problem. or any error. I just want to know hot to scrap webpages which are build with js frameworks

Comment: Then ask that specifically. `But it fails when time comes to render Dynamic pages` How does it fail? What errors are there? It's just that currently your qurstion is too broad and we cant help you. "How to scrape dynamic sites? Well... Use PhantomJS"

Comment: @Vaviloff can you please do help and add answer with example how to use it

Comment: Hi, did you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the content of the page before the dynamic code has run, you need to wait for the load to be completed.

The block behind the page.open would need to wait for the page to complete, if there is an element you know is being fetched from the back end you can lie in wait for that element (see the waitfor example in phantomjs doc).